# Как настроить ibuffer в emacs

Tags: linux, emacs

В ibuffer'овском списке буферов после шапки идет [ Default ], при нажатии на который закрываются все буферы. 
Как скрыть его из списка (или сделать, чтобы при нажатии на него ничего не происходило)?

ibuffer-never-show-regexps не помогло.

p.s emacs 24.5.1

Comment: Буферы не закрываются, просто сворачивается вид. Если вы `F1 k Enter` нажмёте, то покажет, что вызывается `ibuffer-toggle-filter-group` команда.